# Ways to arrange $n$ people in a circular table of $1$ chooses a permanent seat

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways to arrange $n$ people in a circular table if $1$ chooses a permanent seat.
My instructor said you can arrange them in $((n-1)-1)! = (n-2)!$ ways. However this is not the case of $n=3$, if I will follow the above, I can do it in $(3-2)!$ = 1 way. But I can do it in $2$ ways (i.e *ABC* and *ACB*). Please help.

Comment: I think he is assuming it does not depend on the position of the order (left or right) but only on the order of the people. Explaining into words: ACB and ABC are the same arrangement, A then B then C, because in both cases you start from A and go either left, either right, but that shouldn't make a difference because its a circular table

Comment: I thought in the case of circular permutations, you only need to consider only 1 direction, either left or right.

Comment: @Mike: I don't think that's it, either, as the answer would then be $\frac12(n-1)!,$ which isn't equal to $(n-2)!$ in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your objection is valid.

Since one person has a permanent seat, the circle is now effectively just a line segment, with $n-1$ people for $n-1$ seats, so the number of arrangements is $(n-1)!$.